# Add data in manual filter in pivot table without editing the source

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to ask if it is possible to add manually a data in the existing pivot table without editing the source query/table? 
If yes, how
If no, then no.

### Thanks

example:
  pitottable1 has 1,2,3 in the numbers, i will add 4 without editing the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: Geez Thanks. for this.

Comment: No prob. Please mark this as the answer if indeed it did answer your question.